# What's the meaning of "sing'lar"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, semantics, literature, dictionaries

> And a mighty ***sing'lar*** and pretty place it is, as ever I saw in all the days of my life!" said Captain Jorgan, looking up at it.

The term is mentioned in the first line of Charles Dickens's *A Message from the Sea*. I know that it's an archaic word but I can't find it in any dictionary.

Comment: It means "singular".  But here Dickens shows that Captain Jorgan is not speaking standard English.

Comment: Probably meaning special or unique

Comment: The apostrophe signals some part of the word is omitted. Dickens commonly used this to represent the speech of lower-class characters or comic characters (or both). There shouldn't be any doubt which word is meant.

Comment: The second definition for 'singular' given by Oxford Languages courtesy of Google is spot on here. Curiously, it doesn't add a caveat: I'd say the usage is literary/old-fashioned rather than archaic.

Comment: The word **singular** with the sense "exceptional, unique" is (over)used in restaurant reviews: "a singular dining experience".  The word is adulatory, which can be akin to literary, but not in the sense that it is *confined to literature* in the way certain prepositions abbreviated for the sake meter are found only in some forms of poetry (e.g. o'er, e'er).

Comment: 'Singular' and the more usual 'unique' both mean "there is only one".

Answer (score 2):

It is not the word ***[singular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/singular)*** that is archaic, but its spelling.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/history-and-use-of-the-apostrophe#:%7E:text=Here%27s%20where%20things%20begin%20to,reason%2C%20as%20the%2017th%20century) explains in an interesting post that the apostrophe originated in the 1500s and that:

> It is widely accepted that *the first apostrophes were marks of **elision*** which indicated that *something had been taken out of the word*. Here's where things begin to get confusing: the apostrophe would be stuck into a word to indicate the removal of a letter (usually a vowel) which was not pronounced, such as the e in “***walk’d***.” But sometimes people would simply stick an apostrophe in the middle of a word for no discernible reason, as the 17th century poet Robert Herrick did when he wrote
>
> > What fate decreed, time now ***ha’s*** made us see.

[OUP.blog](https://blog.oup.com/2017/05/apostrophes-language-writing/#:%7E:text=Apostrophes%20made%20their%20way%20into,st%2C%20and%20o%27er.) says:

> Apostrophes made their way into English in the early 16th century, first to indicate an omitted letter or letters. The printed editions of Shakespeare’s plays, for example, use apostrophes to show words contracted such as *’tis, ’twill*, and *’twas*, and pronunciations such as *’cause, strok’st,* and *o’er*.

You will also notice the *[inversion](https://www.britannica.com/art/inversion-literature)*, which is used here for the sake of style. The natural word order would be:

> And ***it is*** a mighty singular and pretty place.

The normal word order, as you can see, is flat and has less impact. Though inversion was more common in older variants of English, it has still survived today.